# Saving as a DataFrame after looping in Tweepy, works without loop, after adding loop, saves as list

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, tweepy

**Problem**: Pulling multiple users timelines on twitter to save as a DataFrame.

Here is a solution that works perfectly, for one user at a time:

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ACCESS_TOKEN = ""
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ""
CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""

# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


# Running only on handle returns a dataframe 
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name='pycon', count=10)
print("Number of tweets extracted: {}.\n".format(len(tweets)))
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns= ['Tweets'])
data['len']  = np.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])
data['ID']   = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
data['Date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
data['Source'] = np.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])
data['Likes']  = np.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets])
data['RTs']    = np.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])

print(data)
```

The above works great and will return the user `pycon`'s 10 most recent tweets in a DataFrame. The next step is to add multiple handles to be queried. Here is the code for doing the same thing with multiple handles:

```
#Added list of handles
handles = ['pycon', 'gvanrossum']
#Added Empty DF to fill
test = []
#Added loop
for handle in handles:
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=handle, count=10)
    print("Number of tweets extracted: {}.\n".format(len(tweets)))
    data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])
    data['len']  = np.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])
    data['ID']   = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
    data['Date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
    data['Source'] = np.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])
    data['Likes']  = np.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets])
    data['RTs']    = np.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])
    test.append(data)

print(test)
```

Running this will give two outputs. `data` will be a DataFrame with `gvanrossum`'s 10 most recent tweets (being the second handle in the handle list, this make sense). The second output will be `test`, which is a list. It's interesting that `test` has all 20 tweets from `pycon` and `gvansossum`, but in list form. The loop is working, but it does not save as a DataFrame.

**Question**: How does one save this loop between multiple handles as a DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the data in a single data base

```
merged=pd.DataFrame()
#Added loop
for handle in handles:
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=handle, count=10)
    print("Number of tweets extracted: {}.\n".format(len(tweets)))
    data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])
    data['len']  = np.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])
    data['ID']   = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
    data['Date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
    data['Source'] = np.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])
    data['Likes']  = np.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets])
    data['RTs']    = np.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])
    #created new column handle to identify the source of tweet. Can comment if you do not need.
    data.loc['Handle',:]=handle
    #merging the data frames
    merged=pd.concat([merged,data])
print(merged)
```

Comment: Right, but that defeats the purpose of the loop. If I have a n handles. This solution would be `df_handle0 = test[0]`, `df_handle1 = test[1]`, `df_handle2 = test[2]`, `...`, `df_handlen = test[n]`. This is too cumbersome and difficult to change if I want to add or remove handles.

Comment: You dont need to do that. What I am saying is it will be saved as a list of dataframes in the test variable. I just showed you how to access it. If you have 10 variables, you  can access each of them by parsing through the list test.

Comment: Are you saying you need it in a single dataframe? like, a dataframe with 20 rows in this case?

Comment: This works great! Thank you. I changed the one line to `data['handle'] = handle`